# Wanted to get the name of the label on right click in javascript react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the code basically is to show left sidebar menu in a tree structure, on right clicking each of the label should open the context menu having item open with - {{label name}}. I am unable to pass the name dynamically, its taking the last ones name default. Will share the image ass well.enter image description here

```
import { TooltipDefinition } from 'carbon-components-react';
    import { useContextMenu } from 'carbon-components-react/lib/components/ContextMenu';
    import Menu from 'carbon-components-react/lib/components/Menu';
    import { buildMenu } from 'carbon-components-react/lib/components/Menu/_storybook-utils';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import React from 'react';
    export const getBoldTeXt = (name, elementSearch) => {
      const splittedNames = name?.split(new RegExp(`(${elementSearch})`, 'gi'));
      return (
        <>
          {splittedNames &&
            splittedNames
              .filter((splittedName) => splittedName.trim() !== '')
              .map((splittedName, i) => (
                <span
                  key={i}
                  style={
                    elementSearch && splittedName && splittedName.toLowerCase() === elementSearch.toLowerCase()
                      ? { fontWeight: 'bold' }
                      : {}
                  }
                >
                  {splittedName}
                </span>
              ))}
        </>
      );
    };
    
    const renderToolTip = (name, elementSearch, labelname, istruncated) => {
      if (istruncated) {
        return (
          <TooltipDefinition tooltipText={name} alignment='start' direction='bottom'>
            {name !== undefined ? getBoldTeXt(labelname, elementSearch) : ''}
          </TooltipDefinition>
        );
      } else if (name !== undefined) {
        return getBoldTeXt(labelname, elementSearch);
      }
    };
    const ContextMenu = ({ name, elementSearch, labelname, istruncated, version }) => {
      const menuProps = useContextMenu();
    
      let items = [
        {
          type: 'item',
          label: 'Open-' + name,
        },
        { type: 'divider' },
      ];
      const renderedItems = buildMenu(items, name);
    
      return (
        <>
          <span className='package-row-name'>{renderToolTip(name, elementSearch, labelname, istruncated)}</span>
          <span className='version'>{version}</span>
          <Menu {...menuProps}>{renderedItems}</Menu>
        </>
      );
    };
    export const PackageDesignerContextMenu = ({ name, elementSearch, labelname, istruncated, version }) =>
      ContextMenu({ name, elementSearch, labelname, istruncated, version });
    ContextMenu.propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string,
      elementSearch: PropTypes.string,
      labelname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      istruncated: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      version: PropTypes.string,
    };
```

The above code is child functional component (PackageDesignerContextMenu) and parent has the import

```
<PackageDesignerContextMenu
                  name={name}
                  elementSearch={elementSearch}
                  labelname={labelname}
                  istruncated={istruncated}
                  version={version}
                />
```

the code basically is to show left sidebar menu in a tree structure, on right clicking each of the label should open the context menu having item open with - {{label name}}. I am unable to pass the name dynamically, its taking the last ones name default.
Will share the image ass well.[Image of the current implenentation]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XBPi.png

Comment: Your `ContextMenu` seems a bit useless because PackageDesignerContextMenu returns it without any change.

Where do you pass the `labelname` ?

Comment: Either name or label name can pass, both carries the same.